# Issue when trying to copy structure to fifo using C

Tags: c, struct, chat, memcpy, fifo

I'm trying to copy a structure to a fifo in a process, and trying to read that data from the fifo using another process in order to implement a chat. My code compiles and runs, but the outcome isn't the one i want. It seems that the memcpy is the cource of my problem.

Here's my output:

> test@Computer-H:~/Desktop$ ./chat test /var/tmp/fifoA /var/tmp/fifoB
>
> Arrancando thread1
>
> Arrancando thread2
>
> Fin Arranca threads
>
> /var/tmp/fifoA
>
> /var/tmp/fifoB
>
> FifoA opened
>
> antes printf
>
> struct ok: test, 2
>
> memcpy bien buff: �@�Test: �@�, 0
>
> End send!
>
> Hola end receive!

And on the other terminal:

> test@Computer-H:~/Desktop$ ./chat test /var/tmp/fifoB /var/tmp/fifoA
>   Arrancando thread1
>
> Arrancando thread2
>
> Fin Arranca threads
>
> /var/tmp/fifoA
>
> /var/tmp/fifoB
>
> FifoA opened
>
> antes printf
>
> struct ok: test, 2
>
> memcpy bienEnd send!
>
> buff: � �Test: � �, 0
>
> Hola end receive!

And my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_CHARS_MSG 128
enum tipo_mensaje {
MENSAJE_NORMAL, /* Mensaje para transferir lineas de la conversacion entre ambos usuarios del chat*/
MENSAJE_NOMBRE, /* Tipo de mensaje reservado para enviar el nombre de usuario al otro extremo */
MENSAJE_FIN /* Tipo de mensaje que se env a por el FIFO cuando un extremo finaliza la comunicacion*/
};

struct mensaje_chat{
char contenido[MAX_CHARS_MSG]; // Cadena de caracteres ( acabada en '\0)
enum tipo_mensaje tipo;
};

//static const char* nombre = "test";

void *send(void *arg)
{
    int reading=1;
    int size = 0;
    char *readline;
    struct mensaje_chat *message = malloc(sizeof(struct mensaje_chat));
    void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct mensaje_chat));
    char moi[MAX_CHARS_MSG] = "test\0";
    const char* *fifo_send_path = arg;
    readline = malloc(size);
    printf("%s\n", *fifo_send_path);
    FILE *fifoAdesc = fopen(*fifo_send_path, "w");

    if( fifoAdesc == NULL){
        perror("Problema al abrir de la fifoA\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("FifoA opened\n");

    if(strlen(moi)<MAX_CHARS_MSG-1){
    printf("antes printf\n");
    snprintf(message->contenido, sizeof(message->contenido), "%s", &moi);
    message->tipo = MENSAJE_FIN;
    } else{
        printf("El nombre esta demasiado largo");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("struct ok: %s, %d\n", message->contenido, message->tipo);


    if(memcpy(buffer, message, sizeof(struct mensaje_chat)) == NULL ){
        perror("Problema de serialisacion\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("memcpy bien");

    if(fwrite( buffer, sizeof(struct mensaje_chat) ,1 , fifoAdesc) != 1){
                perror("Problema al escribir en la fifoA\n");
    }

    fclose(fifoAdesc);
    /**
    while(1){
        fifoAdesc = fopen(*fifo_send_path, "w");
        printf("\n>");
        int writtensize = getline(&readline, &size , stdin);
        if(fwrite( readline, strlen(readline), 1 , fifoAdesc) != 1){
                perror("Problema al escribir en la fifoA");
    }
        fclose(fifoAdesc);
        readline = NULL;
    }
    */

    free(readline);


    printf("End send!\n");

    return NULL;
}

void *receive(void *arg)
{
    int sending =1;
    int size = 0;
    struct mensaje_chat *message = malloc(sizeof(struct mensaje_chat));
    void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct mensaje_chat));
    char* sentline;
    const char* *fifo_receive_path = arg;
    sentline= malloc(size);
    printf("%s\n", *fifo_receive_path);
    FILE *fifoBdesc = fopen(*fifo_receive_path, "r");

    if( fifoBdesc == NULL){
        perror("Problema al abrir de la fifoB");
        return -1;
    }

    int readsize = getline( buffer, &size , fifoBdesc);
    message = (struct mensaje_chat*) buffer;
    printf(" buff: %s", (char*) buffer);
    printf("Test: %s, %d\n", (char*) message->contenido, message->tipo);

    fclose(fifoBdesc);

    /**while(1){

    fifoBdesc = fopen(*fifo_receive_path, "r");

    int readsize = getline( &sentline, &size , fifoBdesc);
    printf("\nAmigo> %s\n", sentline);
    fclose(fifoBdesc);
    sentline = NULL;
    }
    */
    free(sentline);

    printf("Hola end receive! \n");

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    pthread_t send_thread;
    pthread_t receive_thread;
    char* fifo_send_path;
    char* fifo_receive_path;

    if(argv[1] == NULL || argv[2] == NULL || argv[3] == NULL){
        printf("Necesitamos tres argumentos:\n");
        printf("./chat <nombre> <rutafifoA> <rutafifoB>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fifo_send_path = argv[2];
    fifo_receive_path = argv[3];

    printf("Arrancando thread1\n");

    if( pthread_create(&send_thread, NULL, send, &fifo_send_path) != 0){
        perror("Problema al crear del thread de envio");
        return -2;
    }


    printf("Arrancando thread2\n");

    if( pthread_create(&receive_thread, NULL, receive, &fifo_receive_path) != 0){
        perror("Problema al crear del thread de recepcion");
        return -2;
    }

    printf("Fin Arranca threads\n");


    pthread_join(receive_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join(send_thread, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are transferring binary data thought the fifo, you should not use `getline`  function. You could use it, if you were writing with `fprintf` function, witch is not the case.

Replace this:

```
int readsize = getline( buffer, &size , fifoBdesc);
```

for this:

```
int readsize = fread( buffer, sizeof(struct mensaje_chat) ,1 , fifoAdesc);
```

should be enought.

Also, don't forget to check the return of `fread`.